# Why are there weird black lines all over my lines during motion or shape tweens?

Tags: animation, line, adobe, adobe-animate

Most of the shapes are fine after drawing them but after a while during animation these random black lines appear and can't be selected or blocked.

[Weird Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kNGf.png)

[Block drawn over makes more weird lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqI5A.png)

[Stay there after rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJG7o.png)

Anybody know how to fix these?

I tried making symbols and animating those or just making a motion tween instead of a shape tween but none of those methods worked. They can't be selected or overlayed but they can rotate with skew tools.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening, but I think it could be the color you chose for the Stroke using the line tool.
Maybe it is not solid white color and actually some pattern color ?